# Display multiple popovers while hovering on text using Bootstrap 3 popover

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to display multiple popovers at a time while hover on text like as following shared [link](https://drive.google.com/a/niyasys.com/file/d/0B32ys2Q6plpRX1E1MS0wdGpqSlE/view). I did the following way but no luck.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"><br/></div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4 class="text-center usecap-border" data-toggle="popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">java</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" >
        <h4 class="text-center usecap-border" data-toggle="popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">javascript</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4 class="text-center usecap-border" data-toggle="popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">nodejs</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4 class="text-center usecap-border"  data-toggle="popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">php</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS code:**

```
$( "[data-toggle='popover']" ).popover( {placement: 'bottom', container: 'body', html: 'true', trigger: 'hover'} );
```

Answer (score 0):

The code which you have given will initialize but wont show the popover.

```
$( "[data-toggle='popover']" ).popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    container: 'body', 
    html: 'true', 
    trigger: 'hover' 
}); // This code will initialize the popover functionality
```

To show the popover for all the elements at the same time, you should use the below code

```
$( "[data-toggle='popover']" ).popover('show')
```

To show the popovers on `hover` then use the below code

```
$( "[data-toggle='popover']" ).hover(
    function() {
        $( "[data-toggle='popover']" ).popover('show');
    }, function() {
        $( "[data-toggle='popover']" ).popover('hide')
    }
);
```